# Variable not defined when used outside of Vue <template>

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am exporting a value from a JS file and using it in my Vue. I display the value like in my template, but I would like to also use this value elsewhere, outside of the template.

Here is a simplified version of my setup and what I would like to achieve:

In my **myJS.js** (in actual app this file is used to call my API):

```
    const appService = {
      getPosts() {
         return 123456;
      }
    }

    export default appService
```

and then I have a **VUE component** that looks like this:

```
    <template>
        {{ info }}
    </template>

    alert(info);

    import appService from '../myJS'

    export default {
      name: 'myvue',
      props: {
        msg: String
      },
      data () {
          return {
            info: {}
         }
      }
    async created () {
  this.info = await appService.getPosts();
   }
}
```

The value is displayed in the template, but the alert(info) triggers a 'info is undefined' error.

How can I use this value in normal JavaScript outside of my template?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's basically two ways:

1. Assign the value to a variable, inside the file, but outside the component definition. So in your example you would say `let info;` and in your `created()` hook you would go `this.info = info = await appService.getPosts()`.
2. Assign the component itself to a variable before you export it:

```
const myComponent = { component definition... }

// Access with myComponent.info

export default myComponent;
```

However! You will see that `myComponent.info` is initially `undefined`. And unlike in the template, the value of `info` will not reactively update when the asynchronous call resolves. Reactivity magic only works in the template and in the code of the actual component, e.g. in `computed` and `watch` properties. How to handle the specifics of asynchronous loading elegantly really depends on the specifics of how you want to use this variable.

Finally: the reason you don't just get access to the variable throughout the .vue file is because under the hood, the template compiles to a function which is executed in the context of the component. For convenience, all of the fields of the component are then made available as variables without the usual `this` prefix. In fact, in your template, `info` is treated as a shorthand for `this.info`. (Notice that you can substitute `this.info` for `info` in the template and it will still work.) This privilege doesn't apply to any other code in the file; that stuff is just vanilla js code.

Comment: HI Mattias, thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I have tested your second solution of assigning the component itself to a variable, and as you mentioned, my simple 'alert' implementation let to an undefined value. I guess I will have to find a way to delay that call until the component is 'ready'.

Your first option looks nice and simple for now, but may I ask, where do I put 'let info'? Pardon my ignorance!

Comment: You would put it below your imports but above the export. Is `alert(info)` your end goal? Why not just run that in the `created()` hook after `await`?

Comment: Hi. Yes it is. I am starting to think that I should not be running scripts outside of the component definition? Maybe I should do what I want to do with something like a regular function inside a Method, inside of the component definition itself?

Comment: It is all starting to make sense now Mattias, thanks. I have been trying to run functions and manipulate data outside of the component definition. But that does not seem like the way to do it. Thanks for all your help!